# Resolving a dispute where the customer denies that the product is theirs

Tags: halacha, business

If someone left something at the dry-cleaners', for example, and later returned to pick it up, but it seems to not be the same item that they left, what does halacha say about resolving it?

Both the customer and businessman insist they are in the right - the customer that the item is not theirs, and the businessman that it is the customer's original item.

Comment: Hello Sara, and welcome to Mi Yodeya! I'm having trouble understanding your question, do you mind [edit]ing to clarify?

Comment: That's basically the question. How to reslove a dispute between 2 parties who both claim to be in the right. Owner stating that item is the one who belongs to customer and customer claims that its not theirs

Comment: http://www.torah.org/advanced/business-halacha/5757/vol1no27.html

Comment: What nice people! The storekeeper is trying to give the customer something even though the customer's insisting it's not his! There should be more of this kind of halachic question, and less of the sort where each tries to claim something for himself. (Or am I misunderstanding your question? You might [edit] to clarify if so.)

Comment: Sounds like the case in Kartidna where two litigants came to court. One said there was a treasure buried in the basement he bought from the other, and as he only bought the house, the treasure is not his. The seller claimed that he sold the house and everything in it, and so the treasure belongs to the buyer. The court ruled they should have their children marry each other and give them the treasure as the dowry. Alexander the Great, who was there at the time, said he would have killed both and taken the treasure for himself.